# Convert function reference to char* and back

Tags: c++, c

I need to store a function reference as a char*, and later call that function with only the char*.

I am looking for something like:

```
char* funcRef = (char*)myFunc;
//...
(void (*funcRef)())();
```

How do you do this? (Note: I am not asking how to call a function by reference, just if its possible to store a reference to it as a char* and then convert it back)

Comment: Why shouldn't you try it?  It would take 5-10 minutes.

Comment: @user31264 I tried, it didn't work, so now Im asking here...

Comment: Please write a short code (about 10 lines) which tries to store some one-line function.  If it doesn't work, post it.  This will be a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: Also, if something doesn't work, you should write what doesn't work. Compile time error? (which?)  Run time exception? (which?) Something else?

Comment: @user31264 its okay if you dont know

Comment: Three questions: (1) Why do you want to do this? (2) What makes you think you can do this? (3) Why `char*` (why not `void*`)?

Comment: @DaiwikDaarun -- The problem with your code is that it makes no sense to call a pointer to char as a function. You need to cast that pointer to char back to a pointer to a function. Whether that makes sense is highly system dependent. It makes no sense on a Harvard architecture machine where function pointers and object pointers may be of a different size. It makes eminent sense on a von Neumann architecture machine where all pointers are of the same size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This conversion is not allowed. The allowable conversions are given in section **6.3 Conversions**, sub-subsection **6.3.2.3 Pointers**, of which paragraphs (6) and (8) apply to function pointers.

> 6. Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined...

and

> 8. A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined.

Conversion between pointer to function and pointer to object is not on the allowed list; it is therefore disallowed.

There are systems where pointers to functions and pointers to objects are not interchangeable. The most obvious case is where the size of a function pointer is not the same as the size of an object pointer, such as Harvard architecture, or the 8086 in Compact or Medium model.

Comment: Correct. However C11 mentions this a possible "Common Extension" here: *"J.5.7 Function pointer casts*" (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.7)

Comment: Downvoted because this conversion is not mentioned in the C standard. It's not illegal. It is instead undefined. Per that standard *Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior.* This question is also tagged C++, and in C++11, converting a function pointer to/from an object pointer is "conditionally-supported".

Comment: @DavidHammen For the purpose of this discussion, distinguishing between different forms of "does not work" doesn't seem significant.

Comment: @RaymondChen -- It makes all the difference in the world. The OP's code doesn't work because it makes no sense. You cannot call a `char` pointer as a function. It has to be casted to a function pointer, and whether that makes sense is system dependent. On a Unix machine, casting a `void*` pointer to a function pointer makes immense sense. It's the basis of how the POSIX function `dlsym()` works.

Comment: Casting a function pointer to an integer doesn't "make sense" either, for different values of "make sense". The OP is asking whether the cast is guaranteed to be reversible. It is not. The degree of "not"ness isn't all that relevant. No means No.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code isn't working is because a `char*` pointer is not a function pointer. You cannot call a `char*` as if it was a function. You need to cast that pointer back to a function pointer prior to using it as a function pointer.

**Note very well: Whether this will work at all is highly compiler and system dependent.**

There is nothing in the C standard that says anything about converting a pointer to a function to a pointer to an object, or vice versa. This is undefined behavior. On the other hand, POSIX standard requires that a compliant implementation must be able to convert a pointer to void to a pointer to a function. (Note: The reverse capability is not required.)

This question is also tagged as C++. Prior to C++11, converting a pointer to a function to a pointer to an object, or vice versa, was illegal. The compiler had to issue a diagnostic message. On POSIX-compliant systems, the compiler would issue a diagnostic and then generate the POSIXly-compliant object code. In C++11 and later, converting converting between pointers to functions to a pointers to an object, or vice versa, is conditionally-supported.

With those caveats, the following works on my POSIX-compliant machine, with multiple compilers. Whether it works on a non-POSIX compliant machine with non-POSIX complaint compilers is anyone's guess.

C++ version:

```
#include <iostream>

int sqr (int k) { return k*k; }

int p42 (int k) { return k+42; }

void call_callback(void* vptr, int k)
{   
    using Fptr = int(*)(int);
    Fptr fun = reinterpret_cast<Fptr>(vptr);
    std::cout << fun(k) << '\n';
}   

int main ()
{   
    call_callback(reinterpret_cast<void*>(sqr), 2); 
    call_callback(reinterpret_cast<void*>(p42), 2); 
}
```

C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sqr (int k) { return k*k; }

int p42 (int k) { return k+42; }

void call_callback(void* vptr, int k)
{
    printf ("%d\n", ((int(*)(int))(vptr))(k));
}

int main ()
{
    call_callback((void*)(sqr), 2);
    call_callback((void*)(p42), 2);
}
```